# Connect to Mongo (hosted on VM) from local machine using SpringBoot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, virtual-machine

I have setup MongoDB on a VM. Now I need connect to Mongo (hosted on VM) from local machine using SpringBoot. What do I change in application.propeties file given that I have that VMs' username, password and IP address.

How do I set up Mongo in VM for the below `InitDatabase` class

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class InitDatabase {
@Bean
CommandLineRunner init(MongoOperations operations) {
    return args -> {
        operations.dropCollection(Image.class);

        operations.insert(new Image("1",
            "learning-spring-boot-cover.jpg"));
        operations.insert(new Image("2",
            "learning-spring-boot-2nd-edition-cover.jpg"));
        operations.insert(new Image("3",
            "bazinga.png"));

        operations.findAll(Image.class).forEach(image -> {
            System.out.println(image.toString());
        });
    };
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override spring.mongodb configuration properties :

## MongoDB config

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database= *which_authentication_database_you_want_to_connect*

 spring.data.mongodb.username=*database_username* 

 spring.data.mongodb.password=*database_password* 
  
 spring.data.mongodb.database=*which_database_you_want_to_connect*  

 spring.data.mongodb.port=*running_mongo_instance_port* 

 spring.data.mongodb.host=*running_mongo_instance_host -- you should write your own VM's ip address*
```